# AWK Lab 3 - Please revise

Tags: awk, computer-science

Write a script called labscript3.awk that will print out all orders shipped in 2014. Print out region, item type and total profit. At the end, it should print out the average total profit (for these orders only). (5 points)

I tried the following code, but it did not work. Only printed "======="

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
printf "%-25s %-16s %-10s\n","region","item type","total profit"
print "============================================================="
cnt=0
sum=0
}
{
if($1==2014){
printf "%-25s %-16s %.2f\n",$2,$3,$4
++cnt
sum += $4
}
{
END{
print "============================================================="
printf "The average total profit is : %.2f\n", sum/cnt
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: How do you call it? What does the input file look like? Can you remove redundant information such as how many points the task is worth? (See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions))

Comment: What does "Does not work" mean? Errors? Incorrect output? If incorrect output, what about it was wrong? Can you share sample data from the input file as well?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a typo in the question or a legit issue in your code, but the `{` right before your `END{` line is pointing the wrong way. Should be `}` to close up your last block. I feel like adding some indentation to your code would help spot things like that.

Comment: `{
END` ... what is that `{` doing there? Indenting code helps to see mistakes like that.

Comment: When asking for help debugging problems with code that produces error messages when run, as yours would, it's important to include those error messages in your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
% ./aw.awk < in
region                    item type        total profit
=============================================================
0                         0                12.00
1                         1                13.00
2                         2                14.00
=============================================================
The average total profit is : 13.00
```

I fixed your code error, and got results.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    printf "%-25s %-16s %-10s\n","region","item type","total profit"
    print "============================================================="
    cnt=0
    sum=0
}

{
    if($1==2014){
        printf "%-25s %-16s %.2f\n",$2,$3,$4
        ++cnt
        sum += $4
    }
}

END{
    print "============================================================="
    printf "The average total profit is : %.2f\n", sum/cnt
}
```

With this data in file “in”:

```
2014 0 0 12
2014 1 1 13
2014 2 2 14
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably calling your code like

```bash
awk -f my_program.awk
```

where awk will execute the BEGIN block, and since no filenames have been supplied, awk waits to receive data on stdin.

Provide the data filename like James demonstrates in his answer